# Calculate the difference in minutes of 2 rows

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need to obtain the time difference in minutes between a row and the one that follows. I would like to use the field `DATE` to calculate and maybe create an additional field with the new measurement.

This is the structure of my fields in my database.

[image: DataBase structure]

Comment: Please show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that it would be helpful for us to get more understanding on this.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `TRANSACTION` number to look up the prior row.

Something like this as a calculated column:

```
Diff = 24 * 60 *
    (Table1[DATE] -
         LOOKUPVALUE(
             Table1[DATE],
             Table1[TRANSACTION],
             Table1[TRANSACTION] - 1
         )
    )
```

Note: The difference has units of days, so the 24 (hours/day) * 60 (minutes/hour) is the conversion you need.